# How to access .log .info. warn functions from Services.console

Tags: firefox-addon, console.log

From my addon scope I am trying to log messages to the Browser Console with functions like `console.log` and `console.info` etc as seen here [MDN - Web API Interfaces - Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console)

However Services.jsm gives me `nsIConsoleService`. So how to access the functions above (web api console) from the nsIConsoleService (docs on nsiconsoleservice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIConsoleService)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out answer was [Console.jsm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console#Messages_from_add-ons)