# Forcing a debug printout from a Firefox extension (Zotero translator)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Using Firefox 28, have Firebug 1.12.7, on Ubuntu 11.04 GNU/Linux

I am using the Firefox add-on Zotero 4.0.17.1. As part of its installation, Zotero installs so-called translators (JavaScript code) in `firefox_profile/zotero/translators/`. I want to change a few things in the [BibTeX.js](https://github.com/zotero/translators/blob/master/BibTeX.js) translator (`firefox_profile/zotero/translators/BibTeX.js`). The way I use it is I set up BibTex in Zotero Preferences/Export/Quick Copy/Default Output Format dropdown; and then when I use Ctrl+Shift+C with a Zotero item selected, I get a bibtex-formatted text on the clipboard.

I can confirm changing the `BibTeX.js` file works, because I can add new fields to `fieldMap`, save the `BibTeX.js` file, and immediately afterwards (no restart of Firefox required) those end up in the clipboard, after Ctrl+Shift+C is used on an item. So far, so good.

However, I'd like to debug some stuff - and that turns out to be extremely difficult; the below post sums up my experience with `console.log()`:

[Zotero Forums - Developing Site Translator](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/14596/developing-site-translator/):

> > Just a question for developers, i'm trying to find the right way to log in javascript code, like using the firebug console.log function.
> >     I tried different way, like console.log, firebug.console.log, alert, ... not anyone works.
> >     How do you do usually?
>
> Zotero.debug()

Now, the `Zotero.debug()` actually requires enabling:

[debug_output [Zotero Documentation]](https://www.zotero.org/support/debug_output)

> 1. Open the Advanced pane of the Zotero preferences. ...
> 2. Click “Enable” under Debug Output Logging

And I did that, and then I can see "0 lines logged" entry in the Preferences start filling, and then I can click View Output - and indeed, there are some Zotero debug messages there, when I click Ctrl+Shift+C on an item, and thereby trigger `BibTex.js`

Except - and here is the kicker - *no* `Zotero.debug` *from* `BibTex.js` is present!? Neither those that I have tried to add manually at start of every function; *nor* those that are already present in the source code, show up? Ok, most of those `Zotero.debug`s in the source are within some `if` conditional, and its possible none of them are hit; however, those I add are at the every functions start - and still no messages are printed?! (and it is visible in this Debug Output, that, say, the initial JSON string of precisely `BibTex.js` is parsed, so the right file is addressed for sure).

From this, my first question is: would it be correct, that this "translator" JavaScript runs in a different context than usual extension JavaScript? If so, that would explain why `console.log()` (or `console.error()`) fails to print anything...

Second question: what options do I have to print any sort of debug *anywhere* from a JavaScript file like this? It seems I cannot call `window.alert()` from there... I'd even write to a file, if I cannot get anything either in the Zotero Debug Output Logging, nor in the Firefox "Browser Console" (which I understand replaces the old "Error Console" for extension JavaScript messages).

(I've also tried `firefox -zoterodebug` - that simply provides the same Zotero Debug Output on the stdout of the terminal, with the `BibTex.js` messages still missing, so that is not the solution...)

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: Turns out, a `Zotero.debug()` will work inside `BibTex.js`, if it is added at the start (before the first `function` definition), and if placed first in function `buildCiteKey`; not sure if that means the functions like `getFieldValue()` are not firing??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it - it turns out, `BibTex.js` has two modes of execution:

- `doExport()` -> `buildCiteKey()`, `writeField()`
- `doImport()` -> `beginRecord()` -> `processField()` ...

I was trying to log, say, `processField`, but I was only triggering the `doExport` via Ctrl+Shift+C - which would not trigger `processField`, it being an import function... Now, that I tried logging only functions in the `doExport` path, they started showing in the log...

But it would still be nice to learn - why cannot JavaScript in this extension code, log to the Firefox console?

Comment: Translators are executed in a sandboxed environment, where not every function is made available. You should be using `Zotero.debug` to log messages.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use console.log?

Just do `console.log('i am now dumping an object = ',obj)`

and then in browser console its all pretty printed when you click the "obj" link.

[How to access .log .info. warn functions from Services.console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276970/how-to-access-log-info-warn-functions-from-services-console)